# Measuring force with wireless strain gauges on wheelchair handrims

Tags: experimental-physics

I have done an experiment using two different wheelchair tire types (large and small volume) to document differences in push force over a course of obstructions that simulate cracks, bumps, curb cuts, etc.that may be encountered by a user. My crude experiment used a fish scale and an unoccupied, weighted wheelchair to pull it over a board.

The tool I really needed was called the Smartwheel but is now obsolete. It had Bluetooth strain gauges between the hand rim and wheel rim and it measured push force of the occupant.

I am compelled to fabricate a "smartwheel" from available materials.  I hope to build a wheel with a wireless strain gauge or series of them, between the hand rim and wheel and measure the forces to compare the tires.  I am looking for guidance on what type of gauge is appropriate and what type of device I can use to record it.

I am affiliated with no manufacturer or educational institution, so I do this for love of science and the desire to help those with a mobility impairment.

Comment: What is your question here?
There are a few things to consider when using strain gauge sensors but that would need some sort of question first.

Answer (score 0):

I am placing strain gauges at three points (on stainless steel brackets) that attach the hand rim to the wheel rim.  I am wiring the three strain gauges in parallel to a Bluetooth transmitter (Mantacourt B24) which will transmit a csv. file to my phone with the Mantacourt free app.  I can statistically analyze the csv. file once I import it into Excel on my computer.  I should be able to resolve the difference in performance between a large volume and a small volume tire over a series of obstacles that simulate real-world situations, e.g. cracks, thresholds, curb cuts, etc.  I need to correct for the larger diameter wheel which will have a mechanical advantage going over obstacles, however small.